# Adding a "Key" Unique Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to copy form entries from one sheet to another. I have a formula to recall the data. Since VLOOKUP only pulls the first result in VBA, I wanted to see how to assign a key value in this formula say "100." Then the next time would be "101" etc.

**I would like to create a unique value each time it is inserted in the sheet, but not something the user creates.** That way I can use VLOOKUP to find that unique value. **Ideally the first cell in the row is what I would like to place this value** but when I tried, the formula broke.

```
Sub AddSheet1()

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("Data").Range("B3").Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = Worksheets(3).Range("B4")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = Worksheets(3).Range("B5")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = Worksheets(3).Range("B6")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = Worksheets(3).Range("B7")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = Worksheets(3).Range("B8")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) = Worksheets(3).Range("B9")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = Worksheets(3).Range("B10")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8) = Worksheets(3).Range("B11")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9) = Worksheets(3).Range("B12")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10) = Worksheets(3).Range("B13")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11) = Worksheets(3).Range("B14")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12) = Worksheets(3).Range("B15")

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13) = Worksheets(3).Range("B17")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14) = Worksheets(3).Range("B19")

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15) = Worksheets(3).Range("B20")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16) = Worksheets(3).Range("B21")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17) = Worksheets(3).Range("B22")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18) = Worksheets(3).Range("B23")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19) = Worksheets(3).Range("B24")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20) = Worksheets(3).Range("B25")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21) = Worksheets(3).Range("B26")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 22) = Worksheets(3).Range("B27")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23) = Worksheets(3).Range("B28")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24) = Worksheets(3).Range("B29")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 25) = Worksheets(3).Range("B30")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26) = Worksheets(3).Range("B31")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 27) = Worksheets(3).Range("B32")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28) = Worksheets(3).Range("B33")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 29) = Worksheets(3).Range("B34")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 30) = Worksheets(3).Range("B35")

If Range("B37") = "" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 31) = ""
Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 31) = Worksheets(3).Range("B37")
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a GUID with this public 'helper' function.

```
Option Explicit

Function CreateGUID(Optional wrappingBraces As Boolean = False)
    Static obj As Object
    Set obj = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
    If wrappingBraces Then
        CreateGUID = obj.GUID
    Else
        CreateGUID = Mid(obj.GUID, 2, Len(obj.GUID) - 4)
    End If
End Function
```

Use as,

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 31) = CreateGUID()  'creates something like 904A8B8D-5EDE-4867-AF19-1BA9A46D9AD6
```

Comment: I tried to put this formula in. It didn't seem to take. I was hoping for something more simple like "100" "101" something that would increment off the last one that was entered

Answer (score 0):

The CreateGUID value answer sugggested by Jeeped does this perfectly I would think. But if you're looking a simple suggestion on how to log and record new values for easy reference, I would suggest a simple autofill of a primer value. All you have to do is set an initial value in the first cell (eg. 100) and autofill downwards on your newly added data. It depends on your needs too. If you add in data on a regular basis (eg. daily), you can set the date as the identifier value to know which date you added the data. In that case, you'll be able to quickly reference the values added based on dates.

By the way, you can shorten your code to copy the values over. The IF will help to stop copying cells that are empty. This is assuming your data source is a single column. If you have multiple columns, the code can be edited by adding in a nested while loop with the same manner.

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Activate
Dim CopyRange As Range
Set CopyRange = Sheets(2).Range("B3:B35")
pastecol = 1
copyrow = 1
copycol = 2 
For copyrow = 1 to  CopyRange.Rows.Count
    If Not IsEmpty(CopyRange(copyrow, copycol)) Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, pastecol) = CopyRange(copyrow, copycol)
        pastecol = pastecol + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Basically, it would be a way that i can recall the information that was entered. I had asked a question prior and I think it's not possible based on not getting any responses so I tried to see if there was a way to assign a simple value to each row after it copies the information over.

Comment: If there was a way to search by 2 values with VLOOKUP and VBA, I would be golden. But since I have duplicate values and VLOOKUP only provides the first value, I needed a unique value that possibly starts with 100 on the first row, 101 on the second row, etc

Comment: Oh and the shorten code would work but I have spaced in the data it copies and didn't want to copy blank cells.

Comment: What do you mean search by 2 values with vlookup or VBA? Do you mean a search with two criteria (ie. unique ID and actual value)? There's a way to do that using vlookup. You can concatenate the two keys you're using to search for the value in a separate cell and then vlookup that new concatenated value. Do you mind including an example of the data so that we can have a better idea?

Oh and you can still use the shortened code by looping over the cells and excluding the empty cells with an "IF".